# No instance of overloaded function for std::string .erase()

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I want to implement a function to read a user input that return a std::string. I also wish to remove the carriage return before returning the string, just in case something goes wrong (has a carriage return).

```
std::string getInput() {
   std::string str = "";
   std::cout << "> ";

   std::getline(std::cin, str);

   if (std::cin.eof()) {
      quitGame();
   }

   str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());

   return str;
}
```

The error comes on the `str.erase`, it states `no instance of overloaded function` but I believe I have provided enough headers and matched the parameters of the function?

Could someone please help me out? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Comment: You may want to check for `'\n'` in addition to `'\r'`.

Comment: _but I believe I have provided enough headers_ what headers?

Comment: `std::string::erase()` accepts two `const_iterator`s since C++11.   You are providing two `iterator`s, which are not the same thing.    Read the documentation of `std::string` for how to get begin and end `const_iterator`s.

Comment: @PaulSanders I believe I have included headers in my code file such as string class and iostream

Comment: A difference between religion and programming is that in programming you don't have to believe. You can look up and post the the code.

Comment: @ChanbothSom That's the thing - you haven't.  Not in the code we can see, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have compiled your code with c++ 11, C++ 12 and c++ 14.
The only reason it wouldn't work is the lack of algorithm header
So just

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
```

And it should do the trick - these are the only two headers required to compile your function.
Also, You have stated you use c++ 11, so make sure to compile with g++ and with the -std=c++11 flag.

Comment: that might had been the problem. Thanks, I will check it out!